# Euler's identity in J

Tags: j

Just discovering J language, I typed:

```
1+^o.*0j1
```

[I expected the answer to be `0`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), but I get `0j1.22465e_16`. Although this is very close to 0, I was wondering why there is a numerical error in the answer while J is supposed to be able to perform arbitrary precision arithmetic? How could I get the correct answer `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arbitrary precision is for [integers and rationals](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/19.htm).

The [constants](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dcons.htm) **π** (`1p1`) and **e** (`1x1`)  are still floating point numbers with precision of about 17 significant decimal digits .

The only way to produce exactly 0 is if your code is "aware" of the case. The composition `^@o.` is [special code](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/special.htm) for this case.

```
 ^@o. 0j1
_1
```